# Prove the following inequality involving Modular Arithmetic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, modular-arithmetic

If $$ a-(a \bmod x)<b$$ how do I prove that $$c-(c\bmod x)<b \;\forall c<a?$$

Answer (score 2):

The expression $c - (c\mathrel{\mathrm{mod}} x)$ represents the greatest integer $kx$ which is not greater than $c$. So, the larger $c$, the larger $c - (c\mathrel{\mathrm{mod}} x)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have to prove that
$$c-(c\bmod x)\leq a-(a\bmod x)$$
for all $a,c,x$, $c\leq a$.

Both are multiples of $x$, and their difference is
$$\begin{align*}a-(a\bmod x)-(c-(c\bmod x))&=(a-c)+(c\bmod x-a\bmod x)\\&\geq 0+c\bmod x-a\bmod x\\&>0+0-x\end{align*}$$
and it is a multiple of $x$, hence $\geq0$.

Answer (score 0):

Write $a=k_a+p_a x$ and $c=k_c+p_cx$ where $k_a, k_c\geq 0$. Then we have $p_a x <b$, and since $c<a$ implies $p_c x<p_a x$. Thus, the result follows.